# BIOS clock sets itself forward by 8 hours when the computer is rebooted

Tags: uefi, clock

Some quirky things just started happening recently. I built a new computer about 6 months ago. The motherboard is a Asus x99 deluxe. Here is a basic rundown of components:

[image]

It had been operating fine with the DDR4 clocked at 2800MHz for months but now I've started to see issues.

It has failed to POST a couple times, booted me back to UEFI setup and say "overclocking has failed", I have never pushed the hardware farther than the advertised capabilities. In response I've reduced the overclock and turned up the fans.

Sometimes it will lock up while booting windows during the first few seconds of the start-up animation.

Most of the time it works fine until the occasional reboot (once per day if I'm rebooting about 2-4 times per day to bounce between Linux and windows.) I repeatedly see the clock being set forward by about 8 hours. some insight into how I should troubleshoot this would be helpful.

If this isn't the right place to ask, Before you close this question please tell me where I should ask it.

Comment: In regard to the time changing after reboot.. does it change in the BIOS immediately after boot, or not until after your OS loads? Do the basics: Try (re)flashing the newest BIOS version onto it (then reset to defaults, save, and then change any settings you need to change, save again). Try a new BIOS battery (yours may be dying).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the clock problem when I was dual-booting Windows 7 and Fedora 18. I don't think it's BIOS related, but rather a Linux setting relating to time-zone offset. I seem to recall there was a setting for the system clock to use UTC or local time in System > Administration > Date/Time. If you can't find it, try this:

```
hwclock -w --localtime
```

Comment: So if it is not set for localtime, and he boots into Linux (and he is in the Pacific Time Zone), Linux will change the hardware clock to UTC, advancing the BIOS clock by 8 hours and then make the UTC-8 adjustment to the system clock?

Comment: @Yorik Something like that yeah. It only happened to me after booting to Fedora and back to Windows. At first I was convinced enough of it being a BIOS issue that I bought a new CMOS battery (which changed nothing).

Comment: I think we're getting closer. Because now Ubuntu won't boot at all!  Windows still boots.  But attempting to boot to Ubuntu it just shows http://imgur.com/jPrLZ3j "smpboot: cpu1 not responding. do_boot_CPU failed(1)" till it goes through all CPUs and reboots. Tried setting the time to UTC but it didn't help.

Comment: OK for some reason, after about 10 unsuccessful attempts ubuntu booted and is showing the correct time. unplugging my joystick actually got it past the boot error.

Comment: Rebooted to windows and now both windows and my bios is set to UTC.

Comment: I think the solution is going to be to leave my bios clock at UTC and offset the clocks in Ubuntu and Windows.

Comment: Linux has a setting to leave the clock as UTC or change it to local.  Not sure where Ubuntu configures this.  Sounds like it is configured currently to change to UTC.

Comment: @OP Glad you got booted there, I was a bit worried for you! Hopefully setting the hardware clock to UTC works; I think mine landed at local time with no offsets in either OS but I could be wrong. I think maybe hwclock=UTC is traditional in Linux, as my ESXi 5.1 hosts also all have it set that way. PS nice gaiters, I guess you're looking into water cooling ;)

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and mark this as the correct answer because it ultimately led me to the solution.

Comment: The hwclock suggestion worked for me tonight.  I am dual-booting Ubunto 23.04 and Win11.  Had the same thing, system time was updated +4 hours after rebooting from Ubuntu into Win11.